# Show all labels in highcharts horizontal bar graph

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to show all labels on highchart
you can see [http://jsfiddle.net/valrecx/fj6d2/3021](http://jsfiddle.net/valrecx/fj6d2/3021/)
that the months are not complete, the code only shows jan, aprl, july etc
I want to show all the labels including those months that are in the middle
of the visible months, jan, february, march, april etc.

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type:'bar'
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec','Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
        min: 6
    },
      plotOptions: {
            series: {
                pointPadding: 0.4,groupPadding:0.1   ,pointWidth:5
            }
        },
    legend: {
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        y: 100,
        align: 'right'
    },

    scrollbar: {
        enabled: true
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4,9.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }
       ]
});
```

How can I achieve that on highchart?

Comment: You can force it by setting step as 1, but then (if height is not enough) some of labels can overlap. http://jsfiddle.net/fj6d2/3022/

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to change the height of the `#container` div to at least `500px`. Highcharts will show the rest of the labels since there will be enough room.

You can make the font smaller, though in this case you will probably still need to increase the height to keep it readable. Here's how:

```
xAxis: {
    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec','Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
    min: 6,
    labels: {
        style: {
            fontSize: '5px'
        }
    }
},
```

Here is a way to adjust the height of a graph based on the amount of data in the series. It might not be the best solution but it works. You'll have to adjust the values to your needs.

```
if (chart.series[0].data.length > 0) {
    var baseHeight = 150;
    var extraHeightPerThing = 25;

    chart.setSize(null, baseHeight + chart.series[0].data.length * extraHeightPerThing);
}
```

Comment: the problem to that is labels from the x axis are dynamic, which means even if I make the height 500px there will be a possibility that the x axis label height might be greater than 500px, that is the reason why there is a horizontal scroll bar on js fiddle link.

Comment: @arvin I've added a way to make it dynamic in the answer.