# highcharts bar graph layout issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, highcharts

I am trying to create a highchart (bar) with a dataset that is quite large not massive, but 40 or so different bars. I am having a problem with the layout though, firstly not all the labels are output on the y axis, and the tooltips on however don't match up with the Y axis labels.

I have created a fiddle,

https://jsfiddle.net/e8bfxh8a/

If someone could tell me what it is causing the layout problem that would fantastic, I have tried adding padding, and width to the plot options, like this,

`plotOptions: {
     series: {
         pointPadding: 0.2,
         groupPadding: 1,
     }
 },`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the chart's height dynamic so it has room to show all the labels.

```
var rowHeight = 24;

var chartOptions = {
         chart: {
                type: 'bar',
                height: data.length * rowHeight
```

I just added that var so you can have a constant to play with. The data.length simply gets the size of your data array and makes the height from that. There's a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27176158/show-all-labels-in-highcharts-horizontal-bar-graph) with some other ideas.

Comment: so this work great when the graph loads up for the first time but, I can filter my graph results (basically it reinitializes the graph with new data), and if the data has less results, the bars overlap again! any ideas this is driving me crazy!

Answer (score 0):

Bars will be more tightly packed if you set `pointPadding` and `groupPadding` to `0`.

There is too much categories to be displayed without overlapping, so you could enable zoom, so you will be able to zoom in into a selected zone to see more details, like all categories ( = axis labels).

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/400jmd3u/

If you want to see how all categories, without zoom, are looking then you could use this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/34pw12r8/ (set through `labels : {step: 1}` of `xAxis`)